# lodash get with correct types

Tags: typescript, types, lodash

I have following types which I'm trying to get the required path without sacrificing the type. But it throws the following error

```
export interface IProps {
  user: any;
  car: IVehicle;
}

export interface IVehicle {
 kind: String;
 color: String;
}

_.get<IProps, 'car.color'>(props, 'car.color');
```

### Error

`[ts] Argument of type '"car.color"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

Comment: get/set and types are not friends, so it won't work

Comment: although you can say `(typeof car)["color"]`

Answer (score 2):

`car.color` is of type `String`. So the usage would be:

`_.get<IProps, String>(props, 'car.color');`

Answer (score 2):

#### From TypeScript 3.7 you can use Optional chaining

```
const color = props?.car?.color;
```

#### Lodash _.get

In `d.ts` file we have such overloading:

```
get<TObject extends object, TKey1 extends keyof TObject, TKey2 extends keyof TObject[TKey1]>(object: TObject, path: [TKey1, TKey2]): TObject[TKey1][TKey2];
```

So it should be:

```
_.get<IProps, 'car', 'color'>(props, ['car', 'color']);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to ease the pain:

`const color = props && props.car ? props.car.color : null;`

othwerwise:

`(typeof props)["car"]["color"]`